# Finder wastes /leaves dead vertical space between details and preview panels

Tags: macos, finder

As can be seen in the screenshot there is a large area in the middle of the screen that is unused .

[image]

I have not been able to reclaim that space by resizing the columns: instead the details panel seems to have a fixed proprtion of the Finder window horizontal width. Here is what clicking in the "dead space" does:

[image]

I have been using Finder multiple hours in the past two days to view images . I have killed it (via Activity Monitor) multiple times and even rebooted the machine: nothing changes the behavior.

Am I missing some setting/ knob to reclaim that space?

Comment: If you right-click on the heading of that empty space you should get a pop-up menu. Try unchecking items and see if unchecking one makes that extra space go away. Also does the "Kind" column end at the left border of your red box or is all of that space part of "kind"?

Comment: @SteveChambers I did try that: only the columns shown are in the selected list: added a screenshot. The dead area is really dead and not part of "kind"

Comment: you could try deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist (essentially finder preferences) then log out and back in. That is my best guess. Failing that, I have no idea.

Comment: Do you have the Finder window in fullscreen? I can only repro your issue if I do… it has nothing else to do with the space, but it must fill to all edges, so it does something odd like that.

Comment: No the Finder is not in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two ways to reclaim 'dead space':

- drag column width (works only on separator between 'Name' and column next to it; 'Name' column width 'consumes' dead space width)
- drag Finder window size (right side) smaller (size reduction starts at expense of 'dead space')

In both cases in order to work pointer must turn into "arrow left and right" (↔)

Comment: Those were first things attempted (and reattempted multiple times to ensure I were not missing something obvious)

Comment: While trying to replicate the problem I enabled View > Enable Preview as on screenshot (I usually don't use it) and I ⌘+TAB away from Finder to Safari, after that was unable to open Finder. Nothing was displayed, no window, no Finder app menu bar, ⌘+N didn't work etc. Only after using terminal for opening Finder it was back to 'normal' and it happened only once - first time. So long story short - maybe it's just my machine but maybe it' worth to toggle 'Show Preview'/'Hide preview' and  see does it have any impact to ability reclaim dead space by dragging column width/window size.

Comment: I tried the `Show/Hide Preview` and it does not resolve the deadspace.  This is looking to be a builtin limitation in Finder.  I will need to find a better program

Comment: I am able to reclaim dead space as described in my answer. So I would call it some sort of bug and not builtin limitation. As of usage: I have always found using Finder from keyboard quite clumsy so I use [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger) and/or [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) for my file management needs.

Comment: upvoted for the ranger and nnn references